# How do I add a margin outside the border of a component in Swing?

Tags: java, swing

I use multiple components that has a border painted. Is there any easy way to add a margin to the component so that the borders aren't painted so close to eachother?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is typically done using your layout manager.   For example, if you are using `GridBagLayout`, you would set `insets` on the `GridBagConstraint` object to the desired value.

Another option is to use the `Box` object and add a horizontal or vertical struct.  See [javadoc](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/Box.html#createVerticalStrut%28int%29) for `Box.createVerticalStrut( int width )` and the similar `createHorizontalStrut`.

Comment: Yes, I could use `Box` but the code will be so ugly if I have many Box-margins...

Comment: Have you tried using insets?  What layout are you currently using? How complicated is your display?

Comment: The layout is complex, it is a Invoice class that implements `Printable`, so I use many different layoutmanagers, `SpringLayout`, `BorderLayout`, `BoxLayout` and so on... I will try to use Insets, thanks.

Answer (score 20):

Another way to get what you want is to:

1. get the current `Border` of your
   component
2. if `null`, set an `EmptyBorder` for your
   component
3. if not `null`, create a new
   `CompoundBorder` (with an `EmptyBorder`
   and the current `Border` of the
   component) and set it for the
   component

In code, that should look like that (sorry I haven't tested it):

```
Border current = component.getBorder();
Border empty = new EmptyBorder(top, left, bottom right);
if (current == null)
{
    component.setBorder(empty);
}
else
{
    component.setBorder(new CompoundBorder(empty, current));
}
```

Where:

- component is the Swing component to
  which you want to add a margin
- top, left, bottom, right are the
  pixels amounts you want to add around
  your component

Note that this method might have an impact (size, alignment) on the form layout, depending on the `LayoutManager` you are using. But I think it is worth trying.

Comment: This method was creating opaque borders for me, not transparent ones. This was a problem. I used a modified version: instead of setting border on component, create a new panel and set the border on that instead, and add the component to that panel. After doing this, the border was transparent as expected. @jfpoilpret Could you update your answer?